# Ms Access multi-select listbox mover

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have two list boxes (lfmVocabulary and lfmVocabularyAssign). They are both unbound along with the form and I'm having trouble achieving certain aspects of the code design.

Thus far, I am able to populate the first list form with the values through a query recordset, but I'm unable to transfer the items from one box to the other.

In an attempt to achieve this, I placed the code in a module as follows

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub MoveListBoxItems(lfmVocabularyAssign As ListBox, _
lfmVocabulary As ListBox)

Dim intListX As Integer

For intListX = lfmVocabulary.ListCount = -1 To 0
    If lfmVocabulary.Selected(intListX) Then
     lfmVocabularyAssign.AddItem lfmVocabulary.List(intListX)
     lfmVocabulary.RemoveItem intListX
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

In the form, I have the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset


Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

MoveListBoxItems lfmVocabulary, lfmVocabularyAssign

End Sub


Private Sub cmdSelectAll1_Click()

    Dim n As Integer

    With Me.lfmVocabulary
        For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            .Selected(n) = True
        Next n
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryVocabularyDefinitions")

    Me.lfmVocabulary.RowSource = ""
    Do Until rs.EOF
        Me.lfmVocabulary.AddItem rs!Vocabulary
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

I am kinda new to Access and coding in general and I've been scouring the Internet looking for a solution.

I would offer a thousand thanks to anyone that can help me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access forms (unlike Excel's userforms), you can directly assign a query to a [ListBox.RowSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/listbox-rowsource-property-access) without needing to iterate through a recordset:

```
Me.lfmVocabulary.RowSource = "qryVocabularyDefinitions"
Me.lfmVocabulary.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Me.lfmVocabulary.Requery
```

And to update the values, pass a dynamic query using the selected items of previous listbox:

```
Dim in_clause As String: in_clause = ""
Dim strSQL As String, i As Integer

' ITERATE TO BUILD COMMA-SEPARATED LIST FOR SQL IN() CLAUSE
With Me.lfmVocabulary
    For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
       If .Selected(n) = True Then
           in_clause = in_clause & .ItemData(n) & ", "
       End If
    Next n
End With

' REMOVE LAST COMMA AND SPACE
in_clause = Left(in_clause, Len(in_clause)-2)

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryVocabularyDefinitions" _
           & " WHERE ID IN (" & in_clause & ")"

Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.RowSource = strSQL
Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.Requery
```

Comment: Parfait, 

Where am I suppose to insert this code? In the Module, or the Load Form event? 

Also, I was under the impression that list boxes for the purpose described should be set at Value List rather than Table/Query. Am I mistaken in this?

Comment: First code block can go on `OnLoad` event and later on the button `OnClick` event to update the *Assign* listbox. You as the developer can set it up as needed. Value List is one option but seems redundant if data derives from table/query.

Comment: Parfait, Ok, I'm trying this code in a copied recreation. The first list populates fine, but when I try the OnClick event, it runs into the following error: Compile error: Method or data member not found. And highlights .List in your code structure.

Comment: See edit using `.itemData` per the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/listbox-itemdata-property-access).

Comment: Thanks Parfait, It seems like I'm on the right track. Now, however, I'm getting a msg box "Enter Parameter Value" "some_column".

It never seems easy and straight forward for me :D I can't express my appreciation for your help thus far

Comment: Not sure if this information matters, but in qryVocabularyDefinitions, I have 4 columns. The first is the ID and the second is the actual Vocabulary word I want visualized. I would like both values to be stored for reference, but only the Vocabulary word visually represented. This is absolutely the case in the first list box playing around with the Column property, but I don't see anything being transfered to the second list box

Comment: Also, if I enter 1 or 2 in the Enter Parameter field, I receive all the list items from the first list rather than the ones I selected

Comment: Haha...did you really leave *some_column*? You were supposed to replace that with the bound column of listbox. Since you never showed contents of query or listbox I was unsure but as your relay use *ID*. And be sure to have both listboxes the same design structure (i.e., column properties, bound).

Comment: lol, I really have no coding experience :D

Could you kindly reflect the code changes in an edited version of the code above :)

Comment: I felt that I was so close. How do I replace that with the bound column of the listbox (I assume you mean the bound column of the 1st list box, lfmVocabulary). 

Also, I was able to pull data from qryVocabularyDefinitions in the first listbox (lfmVocabulary) by assigning it under the row source. But for the second list box (lfmVocabularyAssign) I have no values in the row source or the control source

Comment: YOU DID IT! You have no idea how much this makes me happy!

Comment: Haha...glad to help! To do the counterpart, in the SQL query, change from `IN` to `NOT IN`.

Comment: Interesting occurrence. I replaced and modified the code (With Me.lfmVocabularyAssign) to make it work within the 2nd list box. But the cmdRemove_Click() function moves only the selected back and brings everything else from the 1st list box to the second.

Comment: Not quite understanding. Is that what you want? Please post this function in your code.

Comment: I edited my comment above to reflect the situation and code

Comment: I rolled back your changes. I did not want you to overwrite your original post but just add the `cmdRemove()` function to it as future readers will then be confused with posted answers here. But thinking now, you may need to ask a new question and reference this one. Click *edited ## minutes ago* to get the content of your  proposed change for new question, copying the strikethrough text.

Answer (score 1):

You've made multiple small errors and not accounted for some complexities, here's the correct code:

```
Public Sub MoveListBoxItems(lstDestination As ListBox, lstSource As ListBox)
    Dim intListX As Integer
    Dim selectedItems As Collection
    Set selectedItems = New Collection
    For intListX = 0 To lstSource.ListCount - 1 'Start with 0, then iterate through the whole list
        If lstSource.Selected(intListX) Then
            lstDestination.AddItem lstSource.ItemData(intListX) 'Add items first

        End If
    Next intListX 'Increment intListX by 1
    Do While intListX >= 0
        If lstSource.Selected(intListX) Then
            selectedItems.Add intListX 'Add the items to be removed to a collection, in reverse order
        End If
        intListX = intListX - 1
    Loop
    Dim iterator As Variant
    For Each iterator In selectedItems
        lstSource.RemoveItem iterator 'And then remove them
    Next iterator
End Sub
```

Complexities include: removing an item from a list box deselects all items, so you should store the selected items in a collection. Also, you need to remove items in reverse order, since removing one changes the index (number) for each one with a higher index.

Comment: Erik Von Asmuth,

I've inserted your code into my module, but I'm having problems calling it from my cmdAdd command button. 

Everytime I tried to run the following procedure

Public Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Call MoveListBoxItems(lstDestination, lstSource)

End Sub

It gives me a compile error "Expected variable or procedure, not module"

Comment: Further note, I've changed the names of my objects to correspond with your coding

Comment: The code you're using to call `MoveListBoxItems` in your question is still perfectly valid. Changing names in the form is not necessary, but shouldn't hurt. Have you put  `MoveListBoxItems` in your form module? Is there a module named `MoveListBoxItems` in your database as well?

Comment: There is a module in VBA, so I assume this is the database module you're referring to. I guess it's normal, not a class module. As for the form module, I am unsure. I have code in the form that reference the database module, but nothing more than what I posted. I also changed the form subs to public, if that matters. But as soon as I run the code, it has the same error with yellow highlight to the public sub cmdAdd_click ()

Comment: Can you just revert to `Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

MoveListBoxItems lfmVocabulary, lfmVocabularyAssign

End Sub`. That's what I used for testing. Your error is most likely in some of the changes you made.

Comment: I reverted as you said, but the error still occurs. :(

Comment: @Parfait's solution is more simple. I validated my code and I'm sure it works, can't say exactly what you're doing wrong.