# MS Access multi-select list mover v2

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

As an extension to the previous post listed below:

[Ms Access multi-select listbox mover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990548/ms-access-multi-select-listbox-mover/44992375?noredirect=1#comment77010404_44992375)

I received great help from some of the community members here (Shout out to @Parfait for his continued assistance and @Erik Von Asmuth) in regards to a problem I was experiencing in coding a multi-select list mover.

The first problem has been resolved, however, I am experiencing a new problem in the excution on cmdRemove_Click() button. The problem is as follows:

I have two list boxes (lfmVocabulary and lfmVocabularyAssign). The first list box (lfmVocabulary) has a multi-select function to choose vocabulary words to be assigned to a unit, thus transferred into the lfmVocabularyAssign list box. I can select and transfer the .selected with no problems (thanks to the community), now I have a problem sending them back from the lfmVocabularyAssign list box to the lfmVocabulary.

Say I have Vocabulary words A, B, and C. I select A & B to be transferred, hit cmdAdd and no problems. But if I select A & B and hit cmdRemove to transfer them back to the first list box, C takes the place of A & B in the second list box!

Here is my code:

```
Option Compare Database


Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim in_clause As String: in_clause = ""
Dim strSQL As String, i As Integer

' ITERATE TO BUILD COMMA-SEPARATED LIST FOR SQL IN() CLAUSE
With Me.lfmVocabulary
    For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
       If .Selected(n) = True Then
           in_clause = in_clause & .ItemData(n) & ", "
       End If
    Next n
End With

' REMOVE LAST COMMA AND SPACE
in_clause = Left(in_clause, Len(in_clause) - 2)

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryVocabularyDefinitions" _
           & " WHERE VocabSpeechDefID IN (" & in_clause & ")"

Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.RowSource = strSQL
Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClearAll1_Click()

 Dim n As Integer

    With Me.lfmVocabulary
        For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            .Selected(n) = False
        Next n
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClearAll2_Click()

 Dim n As Integer

    With Me.lfmVocabularyAssign
        For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            .Selected(n) = False
        Next n
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub cmdRemove_Click()

Dim in_clause As String: in_clause = ""
Dim strSQL As String, i As Integer

' ITERATE TO BUILD COMMA-SEPARATED LIST FOR SQL IN() CLAUSE
With Me.lfmVocabularyAssign
    For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
       If .Selected(n) = True Then
           in_clause = in_clause & .ItemData(n) & ", "
       End If
    Next n
End With

' REMOVE LAST COMMA AND SPACE
in_clause = Left(in_clause, Len(in_clause) - 2)

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryVocabularyDefinitions" _
           & " WHERE VocabSpeechDefID NOT IN (" & in_clause & ")"

Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.RowSource = strSQL
Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cmdSelectAll1_Click()

 Dim n As Integer

    With Me.lfmVocabulary
        For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            .Selected(n) = True
        Next n
    End With

End Sub


Private Sub cmdSelectAll2_Click()
 Dim n As Integer

    With Me.lfmVocabularyAssign
        For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            .Selected(n) = True
        Next n
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAssign_Click()

:(

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.lfmVocabulary.RowSource = "qryVocabularyDefinitions"
    Me.lfmVocabulary.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
    Me.lfmVocabulary.Requery

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're running into an obvious problem here, because @Parfait his solution to your initial problem made it harder to move items back and forth, because they are pulled in using queries. I am assuming that with his solution items aren't removed from the first list, only added to the second. If so, this should work:

```
Private Sub cmdRemove_Click()

Dim in_clause As String: in_clause = ""
Dim strSQL As String, n As Integer
'Set the SQL to the current SQL
strSQL = Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.RowSource


' ITERATE TO REMOVE ITEMS FROM COMMA-SEPARATED LIST FOR SQL IN() CLAUSE
With Me.lfmVocabularyAssign
    For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
       If .Selected(n) = True Then
           If InStr(1, strSQL, ", " & .ItemData(n) ) <> 0 Then
                'Not the first item, nor the only item
                strSQL = Replace(strSQL, ", " & .ItemData(n), "")
           ElseIf InStr(1, strSQL, .ItemData(n) & ", " ) <> 0 Then
                'It's the first item
                strSQL = Replace(strSQL, .ItemData(n) & ", ", "")
            Else
                'It's the only item
                strSQL = Replace(strSQL, .ItemData(n), "")
            End If
       End If
    Next n
End With


Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.RowSource = strSQL
Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Erik von Asmuth, thanks for your response. You're always the first, and it's very much appreciated! You're right that they aren't being remove from the first list. They remain there after the cmdAdd_Click() event. However, the Vocabulary words are transferred to the 2nd list. 

I inserted your code into the cmdRemove_Click() function, but it came back with a Compile error: Syntax error with strSQL = Replace(strSQL, .ItemData(n) & ", "), "") highlighted within the code. :(

Comment: oh, sorry, fixed it now. Was trying VS Code, and it auto adds parentheses, so I had one too many. (edit: really fixed now, still getting used to those extra parentheses. Edit edit: parentheses everywhere! Removed some more)

Comment: Still the same error. Compile error:  strSQL = Replace(strSQL, .ItemData(n) & ", "), "")

Comment: Sorry Erik, but now the cmdRemove_Click() isn't functional and everytime the form loads, the Vocabulary words in the 2nd list box are loaded and not reassigned to the 1st list box

Comment: Double checking @Parfait's code, the list is not reassigned on form load as well

Comment: Didn't do anything with form_load, believe I fixed the button now though (sorry for the errors, currently installing Office 2016 on laptop so no testing atm)

Comment: Run-time error '5'
Invalid procedure call or argument with 
If InStr(0, strSQL, ", " & .ItemData(n)) <> 0 Then
highlighted

Comment: No worries Erik, I'm just super grateful for any help you guys can provide :)

Comment: Oh, that was your error (you did `Dim I As Integer` instead of `Dim N As Integer`), and I didn't spot it. Might want to turn on Option Explicit to spot these easily

Comment: hehe, I have no idea what Option Explicit does exactly, Either way, I added the declaration to the existing Option Compare Database.

With the new changes, I still get the same run-time error with the highlighted code as before :(

Comment: Sorry for all the errors, fixed it now (always forget InStr is not 0-based). Adding Option Explicit is mostly recommended, it will force you to use Dim statements to define all variables (and will help you spot another error in @Parfait his original code, he also uses `Dim I` and then uses `n` instead, with Option Explicit off that doesn't matter much). It's mostly used to detect misspelling of variable names.

Comment: ERIK! Bravo man! It works now like a charm!!! I spent more time on this list box than I care to admit :D

Thank you so very much! I'm trying to learn through your examples

Comment: Also, weirdly, I looked up InStr on MSDN and seen that 0 was for binary, and 1 was for text. I changed it, but it still came out with the same error.

Comment: Ah, I seen your edits, I only changed it in one place, you changed it in two :)

Comment: Good! Still don't have a clue why my answer on your first problem didn't work (it did on my PC). If it did, you could've just used `Private Sub cmdRemove_Click() MoveListBoxItems lfmVocabularyAssign, lfmVocabulary End Sub` and it would've worked

Comment: Also, is there a way to reset the list on form load?

Comment: You mean, empty it, or store the data in a table and then load it from that table?

Comment: I couldn't work that out either. I figured it was something to do with the call procedure. But I don't know enough to say really

Comment: Empty it. I have an cmdAssign_Click() button that I will try to figure out later to assign the lfmVocabularyAssign list to another table. But I want users to have a fresh list when they load the form.

I figure the cmdAssign_Click() will likely be a save record type event. Then maybe once I have them do that, it'll reload the form as well. Haven't thought it through all the way

Comment: Just add `Me.lfmVocabularyAssign.RowSource = ""` to your `Form_Load`, that should do it.

Comment: And it most certainly did! lol, I wish I had your level of skill

Comment: Well, just keep on learning. 2 years ago I certainly knew less than you about Access, so in the future you might. Also, https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYMOUCVo86jEeMMdaaq03jQ_t9nFV737s is a good source, although your skill might already be beyond benefiting from that.

Comment: Yeah, I watched a few of his videos, I need to watch it all the way through though. But it's very time consuming